# javascript for insert textbox value into gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three text boxes, one button and a grid view. After entering vales into the textbox and click on button the data should be displayed in the grid view without going to the database.

I need javascript for this because I have to do this operation on client side.

Any inputs please.

Comment: And how does your HTML output looks like?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it on the client side? You could rather bind it to a datatable or dataset and then bind the grid to it.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you

```
$(function(){
$('#buttonClick').on("click",function(){
    var val1 = $.trim($('#textBox').val());
    var val2 = $.trim($('#textBox2').val());
    var val3 = $.trim($('#textBox3').val());
    var row  = "<tr><td>" + val1 + "</td>" + "<td>" + val2 + "</td>" +                              "<td>" + val3 + "</td></tr>";
    $('#DataGrid').append(row);
});});
```

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2008 and i need this functionality in asp.net inventory application.i have already done it using data table but now i need java script for this b'cs i want to add data into grid at client side.

Comment: you just need a HTML table element. and mark the ID attribute DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a gridview?

It is Html table or a asp.net server side grid?

**Case 1:** It it is the Html base table then you can add a row by the following code as Ravi Mittal said:

```
$(function(){
$('#buttonClick').on("click",function(){
    var val1 = $.trim($('#textBox').val());
    var val2 = $.trim($('#textBox2').val());
    var val3 = $.trim($('#textBox3').val());
    var row  = "<tr><td>" + val1 + "</td>" + "<td>" + val2 + "</td>" +                              "<td>" + val3 + "</td></tr>";
    $('#DataGrid').append(row);
});});
```

**Case 2:**  if your grid is a asp.net server side Grid then you will require at least a dataset to fill it without storing it in to the database.

Comment: no its not html table it just asp.net grid view and whole operation must be perform on client side.b'cs i'm working on inventory system.